# How can I enumerate all of the endpoints in a Catalyst app?

Tags: perl, catalyst

I have a large Catalyst app and want to get a list of all endpoints it supports (bonus points if it can tell me if the request method).  Is there some easy way to ask Catalyst to list them?

Comment: Isn't that part of the startup output if you run the app in debug mode?

Comment: Are you talking about introspection, or remote probing? (I don't know the answer either way.)

Comment: @melpomene Hmm, I normally have debug off when I start the app, I will take a look and see if that gets me enough information.

Comment: @ikegmai I am mostly just trying to identify dead endpoints (based on access logs for the last year), but it has other applications (making sure we have the right level of rate limiting on each end point, etc).

Comment: Introspection, then. What melpomene suggests should do the trick. If it's not quite good enough, you can probably adapt the code that displays the information to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Catalyst does not know the full set of paths. The true dispatch paths are resolved dynamically, iterating through DispatchType classes until one responds favourably to a call of `match`.

The debug option does a one-time enumeration of all possibilities that your controllers allow. If you want to interfere with this, you have to look at `Catalyst::Dispatcher::_display_action_tables`

It's a tree-walking algorithm that iterates through each route it finds at '/' and follows each subsequent route that `$controller->actions` returns. It's not easy to read, but you could conceivably implement a version of _display_action_tables that doesn't just print to a table, but does something else instead. Then call it in the live application with $c as argument and see what happens!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Catalyst::Plugin::ActionPaths](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Plugin::ActionPaths).

There is an article in https://www.perl.com/article/inspecting-catalyst/ that shows examples of how to write a script to list the actions.

With a Catalyst Context, you can iterate through all actions:

```
my $actions = $c->get_action_paths;
foreach $action (@$actions)
{
    print $action->{path};
}
```